# Ignore wrapping non-diagonal cells in a 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, word-wrap

## Introduction

I have created a class that generates a two-dimensional integer array that acts as a grid. This grid contains a method called `getNeighbors()`. This method is supposed to get all eight surrounding neighbors, and it does, but I need to remove the overflow neighbors. Think in terms of a Queen in Chess. She can move in all directions: vertical, horizontal, and diagonally.

```
Queen has 8 moves:      Queen has 6 moves
+---+---+---+           +---+---+---+
| y | y | y |           | Q | y | y |
+---+---+---+           +---+---+---+
| y | Q | y |           | y | y | n |
+---+---+---+           +---+---+---+
| y | y | y |           | y | n | y |
+---+---+---+           +---+---+---+
```

**Layout for 3x3 grid:**

```
+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

Now, I am wondering if I can detect if a cell is not adjacent physically vs theoretically (with overflow wrapping). Is there a solution that does not impact the performance of searching for neigbors, especially on grids much larger?

### Actual Result:

```
Neighbors for (0): [8, 6, 7, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4]  
Neighbors for (1): [6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
Neighbors for (2): [7, 8, 6, 1, 0, 4, 5, 3]  
Neighbors for (3): [2, 0, 1, 5, 4, 8, 6, 7]  
Neighbors for (4): [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
Neighbors for (5): [1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 7, 8, 6]  
Neighbors for (6): [5, 3, 4, 8, 7, 2, 0, 1]  
Neighbors for (7): [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 0, 1, 2]  
Neighbors for (8): [4, 5, 3, 7, 6, 1, 2, 0]
```

### Expected Result:

```
Neighbors for (0): [8, 6, -, 2, 1, -, 3, 4]  
Neighbors for (1): [-, 7, -, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5]  
Neighbors for (2): [-, 8, 6, 1, 0, 4, 5, -]  
Neighbors for (3): [-, 0, 1, 5, 4, -, 6, 7]  
Neighbors for (4): [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
Neighbors for (5): [1, 2, -, 4, 3, 7, 8, -]  
Neighbors for (6): [-, 3, 4, 8, 7, 2, 0, -]  
Neighbors for (7): [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, -, 1, -]  
Neighbors for (8): [4, 5, -, 7, 6, -, 2, 0]
```

---

## Driver & Supporting Classes

### Driver:

```
public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board(5);

        System.out.println(b);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.getCellCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(b.getNeighborsAsString(i));
        }
    }
}
```

### Extends the abstract grid to provide business logic:

```
public class Board extends AbstractGrid {
    public Board(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public int[] getNeighbors(int currRow, int currCol) {
        int prevCol = (currCol - 1 + size) % size;
        int nextCol = (currCol + 1) % size;
        int prevRow = (currRow - 1 + size) % size;
        int nextRow = (currRow + 1) % size;

        return new int[] {
            cells[prevRow][prevCol], // North-West
            cells[prevRow][currCol], // North
            cells[prevRow][nextCol], // North-East

            cells[currRow][prevCol], // West
            cells[currRow][nextCol], // East

            cells[nextRow][prevCol], // South-West
            cells[nextRow][currCol], // South
            cells[nextRow][nextCol] // South-East
        };
    }

    public String getNeighborsAsString(int index) {
        return getNeighborsAsString(index / size, index % size);
    }

    public String getNeighborsAsString(int row, int col) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        int[] neighbors = getNeighbors(row, col);
        int index = row * size + col;

        buff.append(String.format("Neighbors for (%s): [", frmtInt(index)));

        for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.length; i++) {
            buff.append(frmtInt(neighbors[i]));

            if (i < neighbors.length - 1) {
                buff.append(", ");
            }
        }

        return buff.append("]").toString();
    }
}
```

### Creates a 2D-array of integers and handles printing:

```
public abstract class AbstractGrid {
    protected int[][] cells;
    protected int size;

    public static final String LF = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private int base = 16;
    private int cellWidth;
    private String zeroPad;
    private String padding;
    private boolean showBorder = true;

    public AbstractGrid(int size) {
        if (size % 2 == 0 || (size < 3 && size > 25)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Board size must be an odd number between 3 and 25 (inclusive)");
        }

        this.size = size;
        this.cellWidth = Integer.toString(size * size - 1, base).length();
        this.zeroPad = String.format(String.format("%%0%dd", cellWidth), 0);
        this.padding = String.format("%%%ds", cellWidth);
        this.cells = new int[size][size];

        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                cells[row][col] = row * size + col;
            }
        }
    }

    public String frmtInt(int value) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(zeroPad).append(Integer.toString(
                value, base).toUpperCase());
        return buff.substring(buff.length() - zeroPad.length());
    }

    public String frmtStr(String value) {
        return String.format(padding, value);
    }

    private StringBuffer generateHorizontalLine(StringBuffer buff) {
        if (showBorder) {
            buff.append('+');
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= cellWidth + 1; i++) {
                buff.append('-');
            }

            if (col < size - 1) {
                buff.append('+');
            }
        }

        if (showBorder) {
            buff.append('+');
        }

        return buff.append(LF);
    }

    private StringBuffer generateHorizontalRow(StringBuffer buff, int row) {
        if (showBorder) {
            buff.append('|');
        }

        buff.append(" ");

        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            buff.append(frmtInt(cells[row][col]));

            if (showBorder || col < size - 1) {
                buff.append(" | ");
            }
        }

        buff.append(LF);

        if (row < size - 1) {
            return generateHorizontalLine(buff);
        }

        return buff;
    }

    public int getCell(int index) {
        return cells[index / size][index % size];
    }

    public int getCell(int row, int col) {
        return cells[row][col];
    }

    public int getCellCount() {
        return size * size;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        if (cells != null) {
            if (showBorder) {
                generateHorizontalLine(buff);
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                generateHorizontalRow(buff, row);
            }

            if (showBorder) {
                generateHorizontalLine(buff);
            }
        }

        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: After some thought, I may be able to check if the neighboring cell is, at least, in either the same row or column..., but I would have to make thich check for every cell.

Comment: what neighbours you want to remove ? I do not see any rule for your neigbour removal ... in expected result you have neighbours which are also wrapped once or twice so which ones will go away ? also 3x3 map is a bit small for example because your neghbours always covers the whole area

Comment: To see what neighbors that I want to ignore, see my actual vs expected results. The dashes designate the neighbors I want to ignore. I couls have done a 5x5 or even a 25x25, but this problem can be broken down just as easily at 3x3.

Comment: you dont understood ... 1.it is not didactic to show neighbours with overlapping on 3x3 because their are always the same. 2.you do not describe any rule for example for neighbous of 0  you throw out diagonals 7,5 why not 8 ?

Comment: No... if you saw my example of the queen in cell (0, 0), you would see that she can move to (2, 2) because it is her North-West neighbor. Also, I hard-coded the array or 8 neighbors, because this is what I currently have. The solution would not have a hard-coded array, but I would like to know if a solution exists to check if the neighbors are valid before adding them to the final array.

Comment: ow i see now ... you mean not neighbours but all possible paths for queen... so use 4 or 8 obvious fors for that